# How to say "My sister is my brother."

Tags: expressions, american-english

I am searching for an expression, slang, official or unofficial way to say, “My sister is my brother.” It is for a brother, whose sister fights her transgender revelation. She wants to be a boy, but at the same time despised to be called a transgender or to be connected with it in any way possible.
“My male sister” is my best idea at the moment, and I had no idea it actually [exists as an expression](https://www.google.si/search?num=100&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22my%20male%20sister%22&oq=%22my%20male%20sister%22&gs_l=serp.12...267658.267658.1.268569.1.1.0.0.0.0.268.268.2-1.1.0....0...1..64.serp..0.0.0.gEBrGy5vtdE).

Comment: You say 'she wants to be a boy' -- "my brother" is the only proper way to refer to the sister who identifies as male.

Comment: If my sister is a man, or wants to be identified as a man; as I am his sister, I would call him my "brother". If people are confused, simply explain his birth sex didn't match his identity/gender, or choose a more appropriate noun.None come to mind now.

Comment: I would go with what @EnglishStudent said -- They are your brother and is a boy.  "_transgender_" is just a label used to describe a situation.  It is neither good nor bad.  Most importantly, _he_ is your brother and will likely need your support.  (It sounds like he has grown up thinking being transgender is a bad thing -- it's not -- and thus wants to distance himself from the term.  Help him find resources to get past that.  His happiness is what's important.)

Comment: When this came up in a kindergarten class, here's the language I saw used (the five-year-olds didn't have *transgender* in their vocabulary yet): "Peter is a boy, but he feels like a girl."  In your case, we can flip things: "My sibling Julia is a girl, but feels like a boy."

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. I watched over 40 documentaries from YouTube (from all over the world) about transgender children and found tons of data about them, including why some do and some do not want to be connected with the transgender terminology. Surprisingly, children from 5 years on used this expression – I guess the internet is a curse and a blessing these days. How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: @Syk - I transferred my comment to an answer so you can accept it.  Glad it helped.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with “my sister is my brother”. It's clear, catchy, and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this came up in my son's kindergarten class, here's the language I saw used (the five-year-olds didn't have transgender in their vocabulary yet): "Peter is a boy, but he feels like a girl." In your case, we can flip things: "My sibling Julia is a girl, but feels like a boy."

Now, eight years later, my son's former classmate has come a long way.  He's a she now, with a feminine haircut, feminine clothes, and a change of name.  Step by step.  It all started in that kindergarten class.

Answer (score -3):

This is my sister. She is a [tomboy](http://www.parenting.com/article/tomboy). Example for the situations like that in the link. I would say this will be politically correct expression although she might prefer to be called with male version of her own name.

P.S. I think that putting labels on how you feel about yourself is something wrong.

Comment: That is not what tomboy means, that is not even what the article says.